# Mysql SELECT IN clause with Python tuple

Tags: python

Python newbie here...I want to create a new tuple from a for loop. The tuple will be used inside a MySQL select query in the `IN` clause. It's not working correct, telling me I have the following issue on the `cur.execute` line.

`TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting`

```
check_tz = []
for tz in pytz.common_timezones:
    if now_utc.astimezone(timezone(tz)).strftime('%H') == '01':
        check_tz.append(tz)

print check_tz

# Prints out something as follows. I cut the output short for the sake of this example.
# ['America/Anguilla', 'America/Antigua', 'US/Eastern']

cur.execute("SELECT * FROM users where timezone IN (%s)", check_tz)

for row in cur.fetchall():
    print row[0]
```

Comment: Yep. works perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to convert the list of timezones to string:

```
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM users where timezone IN (%s)", ','.join(map(lambda x: "'%s'" % x, check_tz))
```

Comment: Doesn't work, the solution in the link to the possible duplicate works perfectly.

Comment: @luckytaxi Indeed, it was missing quoting of elements.